# Why to have small number of indexes with multiple columns

Tags: indexing

It is said, from data loading perspective its better to have small number of indexes with multiple columns than multiple indexes with small number of columns in each? 
Kindly tell me the reason for this.

Comment: Do you mean "tables" where you're saying "indexes?" A table is the database object that has one or more columns and stores records; an index is a way to speed up record searches within a particular table or set of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that each index requires a separate data structure to be maintained by the db engine. So f you have many small indexes you have **many** such structures.  If you have one with many columns you have one structure.

But actually there is better reasons to use one large index as opposed to many small:
1) Less synchronization work to be done! Only one index
2) You can have a clustered index (of course not too big) which is == to speed. Usually you can't define multiple cluster indexes.

So in other words: It's less stressful on the db engine since it can juggle with less data structures. More over maybe you are doing something wrong if you have so many indexes - design issue here. Not that it's necessary to have a design issue but 95% of the cases I've seen **many index = design error**. So you use less indexes (best one only clustered) with more columns:) Insert/update may be slower but this you have to decide for your particular case: what is done more frequently ore select or persist of the data? If select follow my suggestion if not many small indexes may make more sense (or not :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, each index adds overhead to DML operations. Thus the more indices that are added to a table, the more work that needs to be done in order to keep each index up to date. For instance, when you insert a new row in to a table, each index may need to be updated to reflect the new values. This is especially an issue in systems where there is a high volume of operations taking place on a given table.

One advantage to having indices cover multiple columns is that if you are only selecting data held within the index, you can do an index scan vs table scan that can reduce the number of disk reads etc required to retrieve the data (covering index).

If a table is targeted towards transactional operations (inserts/updates/deletes) etc, then you will want to consider each index carefully. If you are adding an index to a static table/reporting table, then overhead for maintaining each index is not much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

more indexes means the data loading process has to create/update more indexes for each row that is being inserted or updated so it slows down the process.